# Choosing Random Cell From Column Row

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular6

So I've never really had to do this before, and it's racking my mind because it seems like there should be an easy way to do this. So I have a table like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
|Classes|Name 1|Name 2|Name 3|Name 4|Name 5|
--------------------------------------------
|Class 1|   1  |   1  |   1  |  1,2 |  --  |
--------------------------------------------
|Class 2|   2  | 2,3,4|   2  |  --  |  --  |
--------------------------------------------
|Class 3|   3  | 5,6  |  3,4 |  3,4 |  --  |
--------------------------------------------
|Class 4|  4,5 |  --  |  --  |  --  |  --  |
--------------------------------------------
|Class 5|   6  |   7  |  5,6 |  7,8 |  --  |
--------------------------------------------
```

Basically, I have a service choosing a random "Name" from the top row. I then need to choose a random "Class" cell based off the random "Name" cell that was chosen and a random number I generate in the service.

Obviously I can do this with a lot of if else statements, but is there a cleaner or better way to do this? Using jQuery is not an option for me. I've googled for awhile, but can't find anything Angular/javascript specific which brought me here asking this question.

Comment: How is your data structured?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.random()` to generate a random number between `0` and `1`.

To generate a random number between x (inclusive) and y (exclusive), you can use this function:

```
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

To get a random name, you need to generate a random number between 0 and one less than the number of rows of the table (to get a random row) and a random number between 0 and 3 (to get a random cell).

To get a random class, you need to generate a random number between 0 and one less than the number of rows of the table (to get a random row).

```css
#myTable{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
}

#myTable th, td{
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<tr><th>Classes</th><th>Name 1</th><th>Name 2</th><th>Name 3</th><th>Name 4</th><th>Name 5</th></tr>
<tr><td>Class1</td><td>Name 1.1</td><td>Name 2.1</td><td>Name 3.1</td><td>Name 4.1</td><td>Name 5.1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Class2</td><td>Name 1.2</td><td>Name 2.2</td><td>Name 3.2</td><td>Name 4.2</td><td>Name 5.2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Class3</td><td>Name 1.3</td><td>Name 2.3</td><td>Name 3.3</td><td>Name 4.3</td><td>Name 5.3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Class4</td><td>Name 1.4</td><td>Name 2.4</td><td>Name 3.4</td><td>Name 4.4</td><td>Name 5.4</td></tr>
<tr><td>Class5</td><td>Name 1.5</td><td>Name 2.5</td><td>Name 3.5</td><td>Name 4.5</td><td>Name 5.5</td></tr>
</table>
<br/>
<button onClick="getRandomName()">
Get Random Name
</button>
<button onClick="getRandomClass()">
Get Random Class
</button>
<p/>
<span id="randomName"></span>
<br/>
<span id="randomClass"></span>
<script>
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var rows = table.rows.length;
function getRndName(){
var random1 = getRndInteger(0, 3);
var random2 = getRndInteger(0, rows-1);
var randomName = table.rows[random2+1].cells[random1+1].textContent;
return randomName;
}
function getRndClass(){
  var random = getRndInteger(0, rows-1);
  var randomClass = table.rows[random+1].cells[0].textContent;
  return randomClass;
}
function getRandomName(){
 var randomName = document.getElementById('randomName');
 randomName.textContent = "Random Name: ";
 randomName.textContent += getRndName();
}

function getRandomClass(){
   var randomClass = document.getElementById('randomClass');
   randomClass.textContent = "Random Class: ";
   randomClass.textContent += getRndClass();
}
</script>
```